# Are there no Buddhas from other universes that are equal to our Buddha?

Tags: philosophy, buddha, scripture

Buddha said "nowhere between the lowest of hells below and the highest heaven above, nowhere in all the ***infinite worlds*** that stretch right and left, is there the equal, much less the superior, of a Buddha. Incalculable is the excellence which springs from obeying the Precepts and from other virtuous conduct." - **Apannaka Jataka**

Answer (score 1):

All this passage really says is that attaining buddhahood is the highest ideal one can reach for, in this universe or any other. This isn't about 'our' buddha, or *this* buddha or *that* buddha. This is about the state of being awakened.

Answer (score 0):

> *Are there no Buddhas from other universes that are equal to our Buddha?*

There can only ever be one fully enlightened Buddha [*(Sammasambuddha)*](https://www.dhammawiki.com/index.php/Samma-sambodhi), like our Buddha Gautama, at a time.

The next fully enlightened Buddha is called [*Metteyya*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maitreya).

Comment: So only our universe got the one fully enlightened Buddha?

Comment: Our Buddha was born into the human realm so he lived here but he also visited other realms and taught the beings that lived there. If you are interested in this, I can recommend a really good book on Buddhist Cosmology by Ajahn Punnadhammo. It's called [*"The Buddhist Cosmos"*](https://www.arrowriver.ca/book/cosmoBook.php) and is a free of charge.

Comment: @Orionixe, - there is an excellent series of talks on Buddhist Cosmology by Ajahn Sona and Ajahn Punnadhammo. I highly recommend this along with the book suggestion by Rain.

[Series on Buddhist Cosmology](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLCXN1GlAupG3yowPq9fiy35EUC_uoEUrZ)

Answer (score 0):

When the Buddha speaks of worlds he is talking about that in the world by which the world is perceived & conceived because that is what is called a world in that training.

There are many subjective frames of percepience  by which the world is conceived and no two frames of perception are the same.

It is proven that there is no simultaneity of perceived events between observers (physics) and it helps to grasp this to appreciate the semantics of the dhamma and how each world is different from another.